# Can you fetch the ARN or physical names of cdk resources programmatically?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, devops, aws-cdk

i.e.

**my_project.my_stack.py**

```py
from aws_cdk import core
from aws_cdk.aws_s3 import Bucket


class MyStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        self.s3_bucket = Bucket(self, "s3-bucket-id")
```

**app.py**

```py
from aws_cdk import core

from my_project.my_stack import MyStack

app = core.App()
my_stack = MyStack(app, "my-stack")

app.synth()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import boto3
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(my_stack.s3_bucket.bucket_name)
    # ^ raises -- AttributeError: 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'bucket_name'
```

Running `python app.py` would raise *AttributeError: 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'bucket_name'*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when `aws-cdk` instantiates a class that represents a resource, its not necessarily something that has been deployed. The value of `s3_bucket.bucket_name` is a token that represents the bucket name string for reference in other cloudformation resources. The best way to get the bucket name in a non-cdk app after it has been deployed is to store that value somewhere thats accessible from your app.

This could be a cloudformation output value using [`CfnOutput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.CfnOutput.html) or a SSM parameter. You could do something like:

```py
from aws_cdk import core
from aws_cdk.aws_s3 import Bucket
from aws_cdk.aws_ssm import StringParameter


class MyStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
        self.s3_bucket_name_param_name = "my-parameter-name"
        self.s3_bucket = Bucket(self, "s3-bucket-id")
        StringParameter(self, "s3-bucket-name-param",
            parameter_name=self.s3_bucket_name_param,
            string_value=self.s3_bucket.bucket_name)
```

Then fetch the param value from ssm. Or you can just statically name the bucket and reference the bucket name string instead of the parameter name.

The idea of being able to reference resources like this transparently during an applications runtime has been experimented with, [punchcard](https://github.com/punchcard/punchcard) being the most notable example, but right now construct values that are tokenized are only understood in the context of CDK apps.